# Changing the name 'jQuery' to something else in jquery's source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to change the name 'jQuery' in jquery's source code to something else.
I want to perform my jQuery operations with this new name.
eg:
`jQuery('#something').attr();` to 
`myName('#something').attr();`
How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var myName = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

This will restore both `$` and `jQuery` to whatever value (possibly `undefined`) they had before and assign the jQuery object to `myName`.

However, consider wrapping your code using jQuery in a closure where `$` points to the jQuery object:

```
(function($) {
    $('#something').something();
})(jQuery.noConflict(true));
```

People who work with your code expect `$` to be used and will most likely be annoyed if they have to use something else; especially if it's something longer!

If you do not **need** to remove `$` and `jQuery`, do not use `jQuery.noConflict(true)` but simply write `jQuery` at the places where I used `jQuery.noConflict(true)`.
Also remember that no jQuery plugins will work if you remove the global `jQuery` before loading them (doing so after they are loaded is fine if they have been written properly, i.e. with the closure I suggested to you)

Comment: Is it possible to do the `renaming` inside a `jQuery(document).ready(function{});` block ?

Comment: Yes, the ready event receives the jQuery object as its first parameter: `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});`

Answer (score 1):

```
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

 // Use jQuery via $j(...)
 $j(document).ready(function(){
   $j("div").hide();
 });
```